# Python: Function Output Result Not as Expected

Tags: python

Greeting all, would like to seek for your advice on the encountered issue as the output is not as expected.

my code as below:

```
score = []
total = 0
def mark():
    counter = 1
    size = int(input("Please Enter The Number of Subjects in Semester: "))
    for cnt in range (size):
        value = int(input(f"Please Enter Mark of Subject {counter} : "))
        score.append(value)
        counter = counter + 1
    total = sum(score)

mark()
print(score)
print(total)
```

and the output is:

```
Please Enter The Number of Subjects in Semester: 2
Please Enter Mark of Subject 1 : 10
Please Enter Mark of Subject 2 : 10
[10, 10]
0
```

Question 1: How can I turn the print(total) output to be sum of the values in the list instead of 0 without using Global variable?

Question 2: Why the list can get append but the score not making the sum?

Comment: It is an issue of scope. You need to include the line ```global total``` inside your function.

Comment: Get used to passing parameters into functions and returning results: `return score, total`, and on the calling side: `score, total = mark()`.

Comment: *"Why the list can get append but the score not making the sum?"* — Because you're *mutating* the list object, which remains the same list object, but you're *reassigning* variable `total`, which makes it a function-local variable entirely independent of the global variable of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
global total
```

as the first line of your function.  As it is, the `total` in your function is a separate variable from the `total` outside.  As an alternative, you might consider returning score and total from the function; as a rule, global variables are a Bad Idea.